# What is the different in putting most possible true condition in if, else-if or else

Tags: java, time-complexity, execution

Is there is any difference to put most probable condition in if, else-if or else condition

Ex :

```
int[] a = {2,4,6,9,10,0,30,0,31,66}
int firstCase = 0, secondCase = 0, thirdCase = 0;
for( int i=0;i<10;i++ ){
    int m = a[i] % 5;
    if(m < 3) {
        firstCase++;
    } else if(m == 3) {
        secondCase++;
    } else {
        thirdCase++;
    }
}
```

What is the difference of the execution time with input

```
int[] a = {3,6,8,7,0,0,0,0,0,0}
```

Comment: for time complexity you usually compute worst case time and medium. For worst time you obviously assume every time that the most complex path will follow. So, to answer your question, it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: This is a bad example because n % 2 will always be 0 or 1 if n is positive (including 0).

Comment: thanks @Dici now i am corrected the code, i thing now its correct

Comment: 0 is even (0 % 2 == 0) ! A number can only be odd or even, there is no third case for % 2. A better example would be % 3. However, it is still a poor example since all the three cases have the same probability. I'm going to suggest you an edit.

Comment: @Dici - I suggest you read JLS section 15.17.3.  There is a 3rd case.

Comment: In this example, and assuming positive numbers, you could have no 'ifs' at all,  Make `count[5]` and then just `count[m]++`.  After the loop, `firstCase = count[0] + count[1] + count[2]`, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there is any different to put most possible true condition in if, else-if or else condition

Actually, the answer with Java is that "it depends".

You see, when you run Java code, the JVM starts out by using the using the interpreter while gathering statistics.  One of the statistics that may be recorded is which of the paths in a branch instruction is most often taken.  These statistics *could* then used by the JIT compiler to influence code reordering, where this does not alter the compiled code's semantics.

So if you were to execute your code, with two different datasets (i.e. "mostly zero" and "mostly non-zero"), it is possible that the JIT compiler would compile the code differently.

Whether it can actually make this optimization depends on whether it can figure out that the reordering is valid.  For example, can it deduce that the conditions being tested are mutually exclusive?

---

So how does this affect the complexity?  Well ... lets do the sums for your simplified example, assuming that the JIT compiler doesn't do anything "smart".  And assume that we are not just dealing with arrays of length 10 (which renders the discussion of complexity moot).

Consider this:

- For each zero, the loop does one test and one increment - say 2 operations.
- For each non-zero element, the loop does two tests and one increment - say 3 operations.

So that is roughly 2*N operations for N elements when all zero versus 3*N operations when all non-zero.  But both are `O(N)` ... so the Big O complexity is not affected.

(OK I left some stuff out ... but you get the picture.  One of the cases is going to be faster, but the *complexity* is not affected.)

Answer (score 5):

There's a bit more to this than you're being told.

1. 'if' versus 'else': If a condition and its converse are not equally likely, you should handle the more likely condition in the 'else' block, not the 'if' block. The 'if' block requires a conditional jump which isn't taken and a final branch around the 'else' block; the 'else' block requires a condition branch which is taken and no final branch at all.
2. 'if' versus 'else if' versus 'else': Obviously you should handle the most common case in the 'if' block, to avoid the second test. The same considerations as at (1) determine that the more common case as between the final 'else if' and the final 'else' should be handled in the final 'else' block.

Having said all that, unless the tests are non-trivial, or the contents of all these blocks are utterly trivial, it it is rather unlikely that  any of it will make a discernible difference.

Comment: Your first point took my attention but I don't get it. What do you call a final branch and why is it slower than a conditional jump (if I undestand well) ?

Comment: @Dici A conditional branch plus an unconditional branch is slower than a conditional branch.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference if you only have an `if-else`, since the condition will always be evaluated and it does not matter whether it is almost always true or false. However, if you  have an `if` in the `else` part (the `else if`), it is much better to put the most possible true condition in the first `if`. Therefore, most of the time you won't need to evaluate the condition inside the `else`, increasing performance.

Comment: Do you have an documentation to support this assertion?

Answer (score 2):

If most conditions are true in if then the execution time will be less .Because in the first if condition only it satisfied.

If most conditions are true in if-else then the execution time will be less then last and more than first scenarios .

If most conditions are true in else then the execution time will be more.Because it checkes first 2 conditions.

Answer (score 2):

Sure it is.

`if ... else if ...` checks are going in order in which they were coded. So, if you will place most possible condition in the end of this conditions checking queue - such code will work slightly slower.

But it all depenends how these conditions are built (how complex they are).

Answer (score 1):

Most Possible condition should go to the if and then if else and so on.

Answer (score 1):

It's good to write the most common condition in the very first level so that if that condition is true or false will be treated first in less time.

If you put the most frequent condition in middle (else..if) or in last (else), then it will take time to reach to that condition statement because it needs to check every condition statement.